# If statement inside of a Click event Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, css-animations, jquery-hover

I'm new to Jquery and I'm working with a grid of list items that are styled as red dots. I've made it so that when you hover over one of the dots, it's given a class with an animation that grows the particular dot.

**The Class**

```
.twoHover{
transform-origin: center;
animation: makeDotsBig 1s forwards;
}
@keyframes makeDotsBig {
  0%{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
  100%{
    -webkit-transform: scale(3);
  }
}
```

**The JS**

```
var numDots = 0;
$("li").on('mouseover', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass("twoHover");
    numDots++;
})
```

My problem now is that once all of the dots have been expanded, I want to trigger an animation that makes them all animate to the same overlapping on the page. I've tested it with a click event that console logs "numDots" and the mouseover is successfully adding to the number, but no matter what type of if, while, or for loop I try I can't seem to make the animation trigger once "numDots" reaches my desired number (25 in this case).

If anyone could lead me in the right direction for a solution I would appreciate it!

Comment: what do you mean by you can't trigger the animation in click event? Exactly in which part do you face the problem?Can you be more specific?

Comment: Question not clear.

Comment: you are binding with tag name, tag name selector will always give you an array. so may be 25 li present in your page

Comment: My grid of dots contains 25 separate list items. I'm trying to make it so that each time you hover over a li it triggers the css animation to transform:scale and it also adds 1 to the integer "numDots". I've been successful in doing this so far. The part where I'm running into trouble is I'm not sure how to make the second animation (all the dots return to the center of screen) trigger after hovering over all the dots. I've tried using if and while statements as well as a for loop but I can't seem to figure out how to keep track of numDots and trigger the second animation on 25.